# When material is counterproductive (construction task)

Tags: problems, material-balance

Give a position where :

> White has all 16 pieces.
> Black has a king and a single pawn,
> White, to move, loses. Bonus kudos if White can't stop a #1.
> Remove any single piece (except the kings, of course), and White wins

Since there surely are many solutions, give your shortest proof game and the shortest of all entries may win. If they are equal, the first poster wins.

EDIT: A small clarification. Yes, you may use promoted material and even an illegal pawn structure, but you hardly will gain anything as these are move-eaters.

Answer (score 2):

Many solutions indeed exist. The hard part is actually finding one. All pieces must be intertwined. With a few promoted bishops, I have managed to find one. It can be reached in **55 moves.**

```
[FEN ""]
[startply "110"]

1. h4 g5 2. hxg5 h6 3. Rxh6 Rh7 4. f4 Rg7 5. f5 Rg6 6. fxg6 e6 7. gxf7+ Ke7 8. Nf3 Kd6 9. Nh4 Ke5 10. fxg8=B Kf4 11. a4 b5 12. axb5 Kg3 13. d4 Kh2 14. Bf4+ Kh1 15. Bh2 e5 16. dxe5 Qe7 17. g6 Qh7 18. gxh7 d5 19. c4 a5 20. cxd5 c6 21. dxc6 a4 22. c7 Ra6 23. Qd5 Bf5 24. Qa8 Rd6 25. Kf2 Be7 26. Kf3 Bf6 27. Kf4 Nc6 28. b4 Na5 29. bxa5 Rd1 30. Nc3 Re1 31. e4 Rd1 32. Bd3 Rg1 33. Kxf5 Re1 34. Kxf6 Rf1+ 35. Kg7 Re1 36. g3 Rg1 37. Rf1 a3 38. Rf8 Rf1 39. e6 Rg1 40. Kh8 Re1 41. e7 Rf1 42. a6 Re1 43. a7 Rd1 44. b6 Rg1 45. b7 Rf1 46. c8=B Re1 47. e8=B Rc1 48. e5 Rd1 49. Bdg6 Re1 50. Bcf5 Rd1 51. Bef7 Rf1 52. Nd1 Rf2 53. e6 Re2 54. Ne3 Rg2 55. Nexg2 a2
```

Comment: Of course I "forgot" to specify "no promoted material", so feel free to use it! (I just say it isn't necessary, and promoting will cost a lot of pawn moves. In fact, even a solution with no doubled pawns exists, costing 22 or so White arrival moves, plus 15 captures, which can be intertwined, so your goal should be in the range of 30 moves...)